# Como cargar datos a una tabla ASP.NET MVC de tablas relacionadas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una tabla HTML en ASP.NET MVC que muestra los datos del Modelo MyModel en una tabla HTML.
Ahora lo que necesito es que de las columnas Codigo_User y Codigo_Campo (las cuales guardan códigos) me muestre la descripción de esos códigos, los cuales están en otras tablas MyTablaCampos y MyTablaUsers 
Aqui dejo la definicion de mis modelos:
MyModel

```html
        public partial class MyModel
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Codigo_User { get; set; }
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_solicitud { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> Codigo_Campo { get; set; }
            public string Ubicacion { get; set; }       
            public MyTablaCampos Campos { get; set; }
            public MyTablaUsers Users { get; set; }
        }

    namespace MyProyect.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        
        public partial class MyTablaUsers 
        {
            public string Codigo_User { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Contacto { get; set; }
            public string RFC { get; set; }
        }
    }      

    namespace MyProyect.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        
        public partial class MyTablaCampos 
        {
            public short Cod_Empresa { get; set; }
            public string Codigo_User { get; set; }
            public short Codigo_Campo { get; set; }
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }
            public short Tipo { get; set; }
            public short Producto { get; set; }
          }
    }
```

Esta es la estructura de mi tabla HTML, en las columnas donde quiero que aparezcan los nombre no sale nada, así que nose si haya otra solución.
Gracias.

```html
@model IEnumerable<Inocuidad.Models.MyModel>

<div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive table-condensed table-sm" style="font-size:small">
<table class="table table-hover" id="dataTableCreditos">
  @if (Model != null)
  {
  <thead class="thead-light">
  <tr>
  <th>Codigo_User</th>
  <th>Usuario</th>
  <th>Codigo_Campo</th>
  <th>Campo</th>
  <th>Fecha de solicitud</th>
  <th>Ubicacion</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
  <tr>
  <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo_User, new { id = "Codigo_User" })
  </td>
  <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users.Nombre)
  </td>
  <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo_Campo, new { id = "Codigo_Campo" })
  </td>
  <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Campos.Descripcion)
  </td>
  <td>
  @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.Fecha_solicitud)
  </td>
  <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ubicacion)
  </td>
 </tr>
}
</tbody>
}
</table>
</div>
```

```html
public ActionResult SetSolicitud()
{
 var item = from s in bd.MyModel select s;
 return View(item.ToList());
}
```

Resultado esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Indica por favor, el código del Controlador, y sobre todo cómo cargas el modelo `MyModel` desde el origen de datos en la Acción correspondiente. Es fundamental para contestar tu pregunta.

Comment: Tu clase MyModel está ligada con el contexto en la base de datos? De ser así es muy sencillo relacionarlas.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en la clase "MyTablaUsers". También agrega lo que tienes en el controlador

Comment: Indica por favor, el **código del Controlador**, y sobre todo cómo obtienes el modelo `IEnumerable<Inocuidad.Models.MyModel>` desde el origen de datos. Es fundamental para contestar tu pregunta.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta @fredyfx

Comment: Prueba esto: `@model List<Inocuidad.Models.MyModel>` , cambia IEnumerable por List.

Comment: Hola, su respuesto no me funciono, sigue sin mostrar los nombres @RafaelAcosta

Comment: @Huntzberger: He editado mi respuesta con una posible solución, pruébala por favor.

Comment: "También agrega lo que tienes en el controlador".

Comment: Vale, no lo había visto, creo que ya sé cuál es tu problema, en un rato que tenga chance de responder lo haré :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu controlador:

```
public ActionResult SetSolicitud()
{
 var item = from s in bd.MyModel select s;
 return View(item.ToList());
}
```

Lo reemplazaré por una expresión lambda:

```
public ActionResult SetSolicitud()
{
 var model = bd.MyModel.Include(x => x.Users).Include(y => y.Campos).ToList();
 return View(model);
}
```

Según [la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) :

### Cargando diligentemente (eagerly loading)

La carga diligente es el proceso por el cual una consulta para un tipo de entidad también carga las entidades relacionadas como parte de la consulta. La carga diligente se logra mediante el uso del método include. Por ejemplo, las consultas siguientes cargarán blogs y todas las entradas relacionadas con cada blog.

### Nota de la documentación:

Include es un método de extensión en el espacio de nombres `System. Data. Entity`, por lo que debe asegurarse de que está usando ese espacio de nombres.

**Comentario:**

Ahora bien, en teoría ya tienes la propiedad cargada y debería estar disponible para ser presentada por la vista.

**Actualización:**

```
public partial class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Codigo_User { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_solicitud { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Codigo_Campo { get; set; }
        public string Ubicacion { get; set; }       
        //Aqui la navegación entre clases:
        public virtual MyTablaCampos Campos { get; set; } 
        public virtual MyTablaUsers Users { get; set; }
    }
```

En la clase con la que se relaciona:

```
 public partial class MyTablaUsers 
        {
            public string Codigo_User { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Contacto { get; set; }
            public string RFC { get; set; }
            //Con esto Entity Framework entiende la relación:
            public virtual MyModel mymodel { get; set; }
        }
```

Ahora con respectoa  los campos:

```
 public partial class MyTablaCampos 
    {
        public short Cod_Empresa { get; set; }
        public string Codigo_User { get; set; }
        public short Codigo_Campo { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public short Tipo { get; set; }
        public short Producto { get; set; }
        //Con esto Entity Framework entiende la relación:
        public virtual MyModel mymodel { get; set; }
      }
```

Para mejorar el entendimiento y dominio de Entity Framework, este sitio es altamente recomendado: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, ahora me manda este error: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MyBDModel1.MyTabla' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Users'.

Comment: Disculpame, me genera los mismo campos de class MyModel

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿estás generando los modelos desde el Entity Framework o estás usando todo desde el enfoque Code First?

Comment: Si tambien, osea me genera los campos de MyModel, la primer clase que tengo en mi pregunta, y respondiendo a tu pregunta desde Entity Framework

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98790/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-huntzberger).

Comment: Sí, muy buena, le hacía falta el cómo incluir entidades relacionadas en el controlador. Estaré eliminando comentarios de esta pregunta para mantener orden.

Comment: @fredyfx: Lee por favor mi respuesta, falta una relación en la tabla `MyTablaCampos` con `MyTablaUsers`, se debería añadir al Modelo `MyTablaCampos`  la propiedad `public MyTablaUsers Users { get; set; }` y en la consulta hacer el correspondiente `include()`.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta tu respuesta está entendible desde otro punto de vista, lo que dices es exactamente lo que hacía falta

Comment: @fredyfx Veo que la pregunta está ya cerrada. Se echa en falta una respuesta o comentario final del propietario de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En principio tu código debería funcionar correctamente, pero hay una serie de consideraciones que no indicas en tu pregunta, que pueden ser las que estén causando el error.

La primera y más obvia, es que las propiedades `MyTablaCampos` y `MyTablaUsers` de la clase `MyModel`, no estén devolviendo ningún valor. Comprueba esto con el depurador antes de devolver los resultados a la Vista desde el Controlador.

La segunda opción, es que no estés devolviendo bien el Modelo desde el Controlador hacia la Vista. Deberías haber indicado el la pregunta tu código del Controlador.
Te en cuenta que tu Vista debe recibir un Modelo del tipo `MyModel`, y debes indicarlo con la directiva `@model List<MyModel>`. Por otra parte, desde el Controlador debes enviar a la Vista el Modelo con los datos a representar.

He reproducido tu ejemplo en Visual Studio, y con el Controlador que te indico a continuación funciona correctamente:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<MyModel> myModels = new List<MyModel>();

        MyModel myModel_1 = new MyModel()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Codigo_User = "1",
            Fecha_solicitud = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            Codigo_Campo = null,
            Ubicacion = "ubicación1",
            Campos = new MyTablaCampos()
            {                    
            },
            Users = new MyTablaUsers() {
                Codigo_User = "1",
                Nombre = "User 1"
            }                
        };

        MyModel myModel_2 = new MyModel()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Codigo_User = "2",
            Fecha_solicitud = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
            Codigo_Campo = 2,
            Ubicacion = "ubicación2",
            Campos = new MyTablaCampos()
            {
                Codigo_Campo = 2,
                Descripcion = "Campo 2"
            },
            Users = new MyTablaUsers()
            {
                Codigo_User = "2",
                Nombre = "User 2"
            }
        };

        MyModel myModel_3 = new MyModel()
        {
            Id = 3,
            Codigo_User = "3",
            Fecha_solicitud = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3),
            Codigo_Campo = 3,
            Ubicacion = "ubicación3",
            Campos = new MyTablaCampos()
            {
                Codigo_Campo = 3,
                Descripcion = "Campo 3"
            },
            Users = new MyTablaUsers()
            {
                Codigo_User = "3",
                Nombre = "User 3"
            }
        };

        myModels.Add(myModel_1);
        myModels.Add(myModel_2);
        myModels.Add(myModel_3);

        return View(myModels);
    }

}
```

El problema tiene que estar en la forma en que se **relacionan las tres tablas** de tu ejemplo. 
La tabla `MyTablaCampos` también tiene una relación con la tabla `MyTablaUsers` a través del campo `public string Codigo_User { get; set; }`.

Cuando realizas la consulta LinQ `from s in bd.MyModel select s`, la condición que se traduce a **SQL** sería:

```
WHERE MyModel.Codigo_User = MyTablaUsers.Codigo_User AND 
      MyModel.Codigo_User = MyTablaCampos.Codigo_User
```

Prueba a modificar el Modelo `MyTablaCampos` y añadirle la propiedad `public MyTablaUsers Users { get; set; }`:

```
public partial class MyTablaCampos
{
    public short Cod_Empresa { get; set; }
    public string Codigo_User { get; set; }        
    public short Codigo_Campo { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public short Tipo { get; set; }
    public short Producto { get; set; }
    public MyTablaUsers Users { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: No he creado un código para el controlador, he creado la vista en base al modelo y madamas, ya lo depure y al parecer devuelve null

Comment: @Huntzberger: Cómo has depurado sin Controlador?, y aun más, cómo sabes que devuelve Null?. Me quedo un poco descolocado, no se si eres nuevo en ASP.NET MVC, o eres un usuario super-avanzado que domina técnicas ASP.NET MVC que yo desconozco.

Comment: en realidad soy nuevo en ASP.NET MVC, :c depuré la pagina cshtml creo

Comment: Por favor, puedes explicar cómo has depurado (según tú 'creo...') la página cshtml sin Controlador?. Esto es de vital importancia para poder contestar a tu pregunta.

Comment: Indica por favor, el código del Controlador, y sobre todo cómo cargas el modelo `MyModel` desde el origen de datos. Es fundamental para contestar tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunto, no uso un controlador para cargar los datos a mi tabla, solo uso @model IEnumerable<Inocuidad.Models.MyModel>

Comment: ¿y desde donde recibe tu Vista cshtml a través de la directiva @model el modelo IEnumerable<Inocuidad.Models.MyModel>?. Normalmente desde la Acción del Controlador que llama a la Vista, se envía el Modelo de la siguiente forma: return View(`el modelo del tipo IEnumerable<Inocuidad.Models.MyModel`>)

Comment: ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Prueba esto: `@model List<Inocuidad.Models.MyModel>` , cambia IEnumerable por List.

Comment: @Huntzberger: He editado la respuesta con una posible solución, pruébala por favor.

Comment: Hola, ya actualice mi modelo Campos como mencionas pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @Huntzberger: Obtén el nombre del usuario de esta manera: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Campos.Users.Nombre)`

Comment: No me funciona :c

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un ModelView para poder ejecutar lo que estas planteando.

```
public partial class MyModelView
    {
        public MyModel Model { get; set; }
        public MyTablaCampos Campos { get; set; }
        public MyTablaUsers Users { get; set; }
        public List<MyTablaCampos> CamposLST { get; set; } // Solo en caso de que puedas tener mas de un MyTabla en un solo Model
        public List<MyTablaUsers> UsersLST { get; set; } // Solo en caso de que puedas tener mas de un MyTablaUsersen un solo Model
    }
```

Comment: Ese es el mismo código de mi modelo, a que te refieres?

Comment: Si revisas a detalle no es el mismo código.  Estoy utilizando un MyModelView. Pero ahora me resulta un poco confuso el resultado que necesitas. ¿Por cada registro "MyModel" tienes un registro "Campos" y "Users" o pueden tener mas de uno?

Comment: En Campos y Users tengo registrados datos generales de los usuarios y de "campos", que vienen siendo direcciones, y en mymodel (que es otra tabla) se hacen registros donde se pueden repetir codigos de los users y de los campos, nose si me doy a entender